# Could not get username from env

Tags: python

```
    Thu, 06 May 2021 13:49:05 Desmond Driver v2.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/bin/desmond_driver.py", line 294, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/bin/desmond_driver.py", line 279, in main
    driver_model = get_driver_model(option.destrier_flag, backend)(args,
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/bin/drivermodel.py", line 426, in __init__
    DriverModel.__init__(self, args, backend)
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/bin/drivermodel.py", line 118, in __init__
    self._config_cuda()
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/bin/drivermodel.py", line 175, in _config_cuda
    tmp_dir = fileutils.get_directory_path(fileutils.TEMP)
  File "/opt/schrodinger2021-1/internal/lib/python3.8/site-packages/schrodinger/utils/fileutils.py", line 669, in get_directory_path
    return mm.get_schrodinger_temp_dir()
**RuntimeError: could not get username from env**
```

Hi there, I tried to install a molecular dynamic package on collab called Desmond. The installation looks fine, even the -h flag shows a good return. but when I try to run some real job, there the error showed up saying could not get the username from env. Not sure what is going on, please help if you have any ideas, many thanks.

Comment: Did some quick searching on `desmond` and I suspect the problem stems from this method: http://content.schrodinger.com/Docs/r2019-1/python_api/api/schrodinger.application.livedesign.login.html?highlight=username#schrodinger.application.livedesign.login.get_username

Comment: looks right to me, I am not a coding guy anyway, but it helps me understand the whole picture of the problem, thanks

Comment: two months passed and I am still stuck by this little huge problem...

Comment: Have you tried contacting the people that maintain the software?

Comment: I haven't, but I found the software works well on my uni cluster by running the same command. The error only occurred when I tried to use this package on a platform called AI studio, I chose to use it on this platform since they provide free Tesla V100 GPU much longer than my uni does.

Comment: I doubt either my installation or the security limitation from this platform itself caused this issue. But maybe I should write to D E Shawn to ask about what could be a possible cause.

Comment: oh, I should mention if I try to run on Colab, it is the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out after **two months**!

The trick is, unlike a local computer or an HPC cluster, the way of cloud platform does not define the USER environment variable, yes, it is as simple as the error shows to some extent.
Just do: （take the Baidu AI studio as example）

```
echo “export USER=aistudio” >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

that’s it, and then, desmond will be able to up and running, I believe on Google Colab, the solution should be very similar.
The best way to find the correct USER value for your system is use "printenv" and look for the $HOME variable, your username should be as part of $HOME, then you just copy that name and give it to the new $USER variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
```

The current user name will be returned by this.

eg

```
>>> import getpass
>>> print(getpass.getuser())
root
>>>
```

Comment: While this will work locally the issue however is still with this `desmond` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this method soon.

Comment: yeah, it could print the username as it is ,but still, the same error still there if I run the software again